# Fetch Text and Values both from Touch UI Dropdown in AEM

Tags: aem, sightly

I have a static list of drop down,but i want to fetch both value and Text from the drop down in AEM touch UI.

```
 <articleType
           jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
           sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/form/select"
           fieldLabel="Article Type"
           name="./articleType">
            <items jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
                    <select
                         jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                           text="Select Icon"
                           value=""/>
                           <article
                             jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                             text="Article"
                             value="article"/>
                           <video
                             jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                             text="Video"
                             value="video"/>
                          <infographic
                             jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                              text="Infographic"
                              value="graph"/>
                                          </items>
                                         </articleType>
```

Now I want to fetch it like `<i class="article-icon icon"  />`. I can fetch "icon class" from "value" but i need to always have some test conditions to fetch the text.
So i want a solution for this.

Comment: Why not just make the value a composite of what's in the value and the text? They're both static anyway, right? Or infer the text from the value in the back-end code? What's the exact use case?

Comment: I don't want to make any operation,so composition not preferable for me.

Answer (score 0):

I have used data sources for this kind of requirements. In the example listed below, a jsp file is used. You can very well create WCMUsePojo class and call it in a HTML to refer the dynamic text and value pairs.

Please check:

https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/using/creating-granite-datasource.html